# Macro para copiar de uma planilha e colar somente em células visíveis de outra

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Preciso copiar a coluna "L" da planilha "DIVISAO" para as células filtradas da coluna "L" da planilha "DPTO".
Ou seja, preciso de uma macro que busque a informação numa planilha e cole somente nas células visíveis da outra.

Consegui fazer duas macros: a 1ª busca informações de outra planilha "DIVISÃO" e cola na planilha "DPTO". Até aí ok. Só que eu preciso colar estas informações somente nas células visíveis (filtro), e esta macro cola nas células ocultas também.
A 2ª macro copia e cola nas células visíveis, só que as tabelas precisam estar na mesma planilha. Não consegui deixar as tabelas em planilhas separadas e executar a macro.

O que eu preciso é: buscar dados de uma planilha e colar somente nas células visíveis (FILTRADA) da outra planilha.

Tentei unir as duas, através da CALL, mas quando fui executar deu uma mensagem de erro dizendo que é incompatível.

Abaixo seguem as macros:

```
Sub COPIARPLANILHA()
'
' COPIARPLANILHA Macro
'

Sheets("DIVISÃO").Select
Range("L7:L714").Select
Range("L7:L714").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DPTO").Select
Range("L7").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("G1").Select
End Sub


Sub Copiar_Celulas_Visiveis()
Set too = Application.InputBox("Selecione o intervalo de células de destino", Type:=8)
For Each Cell In from
Cell.Copy
For Each thing In too
If thing.EntireRow.RowHeight > 0 Then
thing.PasteSpecial
Set too = thing.Offset(1).Resize(too.Rows.Count)
Exit For
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Você já tem parte do código? Já tentou gravar uma macro deste procedimento para ver o código que é gerado automaticamente?

Comment: OI. Encontrei essas duas, só que uma é pra copiar da outra planilha. A outra cola em células visíveis, mas tem q estar na mesma planilha. Não consigo fazer ela "puxar" da outra... Seguem abaixo:

Comment: Copiar_Celulas_Visiveis()
Set too = Application.InputBox("Selecione o intervalo de células de destino", Type:=8)
For Each Cell In from
Cell.Copy
For Each thing In too
If thing.EntireRow.RowHeight > 0 Then
thing.PasteSpecial
Set too = thing.Offset(1).Resize(too.Rows.Count)
Exit For
End If
Next
Next
End Sub

Comment: Sub COPIARPLANILHA()
'
' COPIARPLANILHA Macro
'

Sheets("DIVISÃO").Select
Range("L7:L714").Select
Range("L7:L714").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DPTO").Select
Range("L7").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("G1").Select
End Sub

Comment: Coloque estes códigos no corpo da pergunta, e então tente deixar mais claro porque você não conseguiu juntar as duas subs. O que você tentou com elas? Deu algum erro? Qual? Com a edição sua pergunta será reavaliada e poderá ser reaberta.

Answer (score 2):

Quando gravar a macro, copie e quando colar selecione de `L7` até `L`(número que quiser) depois segure <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (Alt + ponto e virgula) Este comando permite selecionar apenas dados filtrados, ignorando os ocultos.